# Global List not made global

Tags: python, global-variables

Excerpt of my code:

```
my_list = []

def scrape_the_web():
    # some code for scraping the web
    global my_list
    my_list.append(data scraped from web)

def print_list():
    print(my_list)     # Output []
```

Not sure why is it not working.

Comment: This should work. Did you try appending a constant? Maybe your scraping results are ```None```?

Comment: When I `print(my_list)` inside `scrape_the_web()`, it displayed the results. It just didn't seem to 'move' to the other functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you never call `scrape_the_web`. This would work:

```
my_list = []

def scrape_the_web():
    global my_list
    my_list.append("x")

def print_list():
    print(my_list)

scrape_the_web()
print_list()
```

**Update**: BTW, since you don't change `my_list` but only append to it, the `global` is not strictly necessary, but it might make your code clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to elaborate on the previous answer by myke.

In programming, **functions** are only *definitions* of a set of tasks that you can *re-use*. However a user-defined function is not automatically called. The commands you put inside `scrape_the_web()` are only commands stored in memory, they are never *executed*.

call the method just before you use `print_list()`

```py
scrape_the_web()
print_list()
```

You need to call the function using its name (i.e `scrape_the_web()`) for the code inside to do anything at all.

Also `python` uses a method of accessing variables called `Call by Sharing`. This essentially means that a passed in variable **cannot** be modified by *assignment* unless it is a global variable. However it **can** be modified if you modify the variable's properties. That is, if you use in-built methods for the variable (i.e `append()` for `list`).

So in this case, since you are modifying `my_list`'s *property*, it does not necessarily have to be in global scope.
However, if you tried to use assignment operations instead of `append()`, like so-

```py
my_list += ["x"]
```

You'd have to declare `my_list` as a global variable for it to change.